# Google play billing crashes on Api level bellow 19

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

According to google's documentation, google play billing should work on API 8 and later, but isn't working.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview

I implemented the basic guide from their github:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2

then I removed everything I didn't need, kept the core and transport to my real app

everything seems to run fine in my tests but when i deploy to production a huge amount of crashes were launched even before load the first activity, during the app initialization:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner-5.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner-5.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner-5, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
      at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.billing.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:73)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.util.App$2.run(App.java:302)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

the method which fails is:

```
/**
 * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the
 * Base64-encoded public key.
 *
 * @param encodedPublicKey Base64-encoded public key
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if encodedPublicKey is invalid
 */
public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

this method is COPY/PASTE from google's example, no modifications on my side not even variables renaming...

my class itself doens't even import the missing class referred in the exception `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey` so it means this class is used by some of google's inner api call and was not included in the package avaible for import

`implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'`

my question is how to use google billing on android api lvl 15 - 18 (my app minimum api level is 15)?

what is the minimum package available i can import in order to provide all needed classes since google didn't?

i checked on maven and the conscrypt package itself is 5MB... i'm not willing to import 5MB of api since my WHOLE APP is 5MB i would make it twice bigger and it doesn't make sence because if there is any device still using android 4.3 or older it is a device with very limited resources and is not reasonable to have su much largger apk for it

===========UPDATE=============

i imported the dependency mentioned in comments but i'm still getting the same exception

```
olderImplementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:1.2.0'
```

Comment: This looks like part of https://github.com/google/conscrypt and the package mentioned there is `implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:1.2.0'` 3.4MB according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.conscrypt/conscrypt-android/1.2.0. But before importing anything have you tried to run the release apk, to see if it is reproducible? Do you have minification enabled?

Comment: the error is reproducible as i described only on api below 19... i dont have minification enabled